# How to obfuscate html/javascript online with GAE?

Tags: javascript, python, django, google-app-engine, obfuscation

I would like to keep normal html/javascript code on GAE server, but during page display

```
self.response.out.write(template.render('templates/page.html', template_values))
```

it should be obfuscated.
How can I do the same? Are there any ready-for-use tools?

Comment: Why the hell do you want to do this? Nobody will steal your HTML code anyway and if someone wants to do it, he'll just run it through one of the many tools which will re-format unformatted html/javascript. The only useful thing is minifying JavaScript/CSS to reduce its size; and that should preferably be done on the commandline so it doesn't have to be done on every request.

Comment: @ThiefMaster, agree that it shouldn't be done with any request. Probably, it can be done somehow during/before files upload? But looks like there is no ready solution...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For Javascript the process is not called obfuscation, but usually compression.

Tools:

r.js

http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html

YUI compressor:

http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/

Please note that there is no point of obfuscating HTML. Also please note that this does not prevent people to read your code, only make reading it slower.